# PHP Optional Function Arguments

Tags: php

I'm a little stuck trying to create a function that takes a single, optional argument. Instead of this being a string I'd like it to be the result of a function (or even better, a DateTime object). Essentially - I want the user to either pass in a DateTime object, or for the function to resort to todays date if no arguments are supplied. Is this possible with PHP? By trying to create the new object in the function header as such

```
function myDateFunction($date = new DateTime()){
//My function goes here.
}
```

causes PHP to fall over.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is possible if you move `$date` instantiation to function body:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function myDateFunction(DateTime $date = null){
    if($date === null){
        $date = new DateTime();
    }

    return $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
}

echo
    myDateFunction(),
    PHP_EOL,
    myDateFunction(DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '11.11.2011'));
?>
```

Result:

```
15.09.2013 17:25:02
11.11.2011 17:25:02
```

---

From [***php.net***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type hinting allowing NULL value

Comment: "Yes. it is possible:" --- it's not. Don't confuse newbies

Answer (score 5):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-154

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
function myDateFunction($date = null){
    if(is_null($date) || !($date instanceof DateTime)) {
        $date = new DateTime();
    }

    return $date;
}

var_dump(myDateFunction());
```

Comment: Thank you sir for copying the solution that I've suggested with a minor modification(Who ever edited this).

Comment: Haha, @OlegTikhonov, I didn't.

Comment: Last time I've checked, PHP evaluates
if(!($date instanceof DateTime))
the same as
if($date !instanceof DateTime)

but nevermind :)

Comment: @OlegTikhonov: checked times: me ( answered 59 mins ago ), you ( answered 58 mins ago ) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use other option:

```
function myDateFunction($date = null){
 if(is_null($date)) $date = new DateTime();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myDateFunc($date = null){
   if(!isset($date) || $date !instanceof DateTime){
     $date = new DateTime()
   }
   /* YOur code here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for optional argument in your function, you can write code like

```
function myDateFunction($date = ''){
         //My function goes here.
         if($date==''){ $date = new DateTime()}
    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: It's conventionally to use `null` instead of empty string to express the lack of data passed.